# Solving $2\left(\sqrt{2s-16}-\sqrt{s}\right)-8=0$

Tags: calculus, roots

I am trying to solve the equation 
$$2\left(\sqrt{2s-16}-\sqrt{s}\right)-8=0$$ 
Using regular method I found two roots of this namely $32(2+\sqrt{3})$ and $32(2-\sqrt{3})$. But when I tried to confirm them only $32(2+\sqrt{3})$ worked as a root whereas $32(2-\sqrt{3})$ gave me negative value.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you mean by "regular method"? If you mean adjusting and squaring several times to get rid of the square roots, then note squaring can sometimes introduce extraneous solutions. It would help us to better help you if you showed your work by editing your question to include this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes...I mean the same by regular method....

Comment: @Nrk7991 Thanks for the prompt response, but I'm not sure what "I mean the same by regular method" means. The "same" what? Do you mean what I outlined in my comment to you? Please be clear & specific. It would also help me to know what you're talking & asking about if, as I requested earlier, you show your work in the question text. Thanks.

Comment: Yes...whatever you said in the comment that is adjusting and squaring several times to get rid of the square roots is the way I used to solve the eqaution.

Comment: Thanks for replying and confirming what you meant.

Comment: In fact when I substitute $32(2-\sqrt{3})$ in my original equation I got the answer as $-11.7128$ and here I got stuck. Can you tell me what does extraneous solution means.

Comment: By extraneous solution, I mean a solution that works for your final set of expression(s), but not your original ones, due to additional (i.e., "extraneous") solutions being introduced by the solution method, in this case by squaring because both $x$ and $-x$ are solutions to $x^2 = c$ for any non-negative $c$. This is basically what Kavi Rama Murthy's answer explains in more detail. Note there are other means that extraneous solutions may be introduced other than by squaring but, in my experience, squaring is the most common one.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you square an equation you get additional roots. For example $x=1$ has a unique solution but $x^{2}=1^{2}$ has two solutions $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Your 'regular method' involves squaring so you got an extra root. After getting the two values for $s$ you have to go back to the given equation and keep only the one that really satisfies that equation.

Comment: Yes....you are right....thanks

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $s\geq8$, but $32(2-\sqrt3)<8$, which says that $32(2-\sqrt3)$ is not a root of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

First, rewrite your expression as: $2\sqrt{2s-16}=8+2\sqrt{s}$; in other words: $\sqrt{2s-16}=4+\sqrt{s}$. Let $P(s)=\sqrt{2s-16}$ and $Q(s)=4+\sqrt{s}$.

Now as a general rule, when you have to find the solution of an equation with root, you have to solve a system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
P(s)\geq0
\\ Q(s)\geq0
\\ P(s)^2=Q(s)^2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

If you substitute:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{2s-16}\geq0
\\ 4+\sqrt{s}\geq0
\\ (\sqrt{2s-16})^2=(4+\sqrt{s})^2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Solving, I obtain only one solution: $32(2+\sqrt{3})$.